# How do make a function that verifies if a piece of string is the mirror of another using a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, palindrome

So I have this piece of code:

```
def check_if_mirror(ch_1, ch_2):
    if len(ch_1) != len(ch_2):
        return False
    nb_car = len(ch_1)
    i = 0
    while i < nb_car:
        if ch_1[i] != ch_2[nb_car-1-i]:
            return False
        i = i+1
    return True
```

What I want to do is make this same function (which checks if two pieces of string are mirrored) with a for loop instead of a while loop. I made this code:

```
def check_if_mirror(ch_1, ch_2):
    if len(ch_1) != len(ch_2):
        return False
    ch_1 = ch_1[::-1]
    for i in ch_1:
        if ch_1 == ch_2:
            return True
        return False
```

But the problem with this one is that it works completely fine without the for loop.

Comment: Do you have to use a `for` loop? Otherwise you could juse use `ch_1 == ch_2[::-1]`

Comment: You're comparing a single character in `ch_1` with the entire string `ch_2`. You need to compare with just the character at the same index. Also, you can't return `True` immediately, only if you make it through the entire loop without a failing comparison.

Comment: You can return `False` immediately if the characters don't match. Then return `True` at the end.

Comment: Yes I need to use a for loop

Comment: Start with `for index, char in enumerate(ch_1):`

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. What does enumerate() do and why are there 2 variables created of index and char.

Comment: `enumerate()` returns a sequence of indexes and contents. So you can then check `if char != ch_2[index]:`

Comment: If you don't know what a function does, read the documentation to find out.